# window.unbeforeunload show div IE7 problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, internet-explorer-7

Currently I am developing a web application for which I am using a pre-loader icon. What I want is that the pre-loader becomes visible every time the user navigates to another page or refreshes the page. So far I have the following solution:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() { $("applicationdisabler").show(); };
```

For Safari and Firefox it works fine when the user clicks a link or refreshes the page. However in IE7 the div only becomes visible when the user clicks a link and NOT when the user refreshes the page.

The user can refresh the page by hitting <kbd>F5</kbd> (on Windows) or any other possible way the browser provided.

Of course I have been looking for some workarounds already. The following code shows the alert in IE7, but the div still doesn't become visible.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() { $("applicationdisabler").show(); alert("come on!"); };
```

The code of my div:

```
<div id="applicationdisabler"><img src="images/preloader.gif" /></div>
```

Hopefully someone can help me out.

Comment: I assume the code isn't commented-out in your real test? (It is above; in fact, the above is a syntax error.) Also, can you show your markup (e.g., the div in question)?

Comment: Oops. You are totally right. But yeah, it isn't commented-out in my "real" code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use just use the onLoad listener instead?  Although it would be slightly slower it should be more reliable.

Actually after a bit of looking around I'm not sure modifying the DOM makes any sense unless the `onBeforeUnload` handler returns `false` first - i.e. forces the user to stay on the same page.

As I understand it the `onBeforeUnload` event is fired **just** before the page is unloaded, so if you don't return `false` the browser will unload the page and DOM, and any JavaScript executed after that will be pointless.

That doesn't quite explain why JavaScript isn't executed properly **in** the `onBeforeUnload` function, but from what I've seen sites only use the `window.alert` or `window.prompt` dialogs to ask the user if they want to leave the site, and then often executing JavaScript if the user decides to stay.

Hence I'm guessing that some browsers may not allow DOM manipulation when this event is fired - since if the page is unloaded any DOM manipulation done is completely pointless.

So either:

1. Return `false` in your `onBeforeUnload` method, and then show your preloader (although this will stop navigation to the next page)
2. Use the `onLoad` event of the next page to show the preloader image instead

Also note: Opera versions 9.5 and below do not support this event (I'm unsure about later versions) but GMail does manage to catch the back button in Opera.

Possibly related is [this security warning](http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/24911/discuss) for IE7's implementation of the `onBeforeUnload` event - it's possible Microsoft patched it in a way that prevents the things you're trying to do. And I **know** IE6 and below don't allow commands like `document.location=''` in the `onBeforeUnload` handler for security reasons.

Comment: The code is working fine in other browsers (Safari and Firefox) but not in IE. Don't think it is a code problem but more a restriction of IE.

I am using ASP.NET and I don't use flush in the response. The thing with the onload is that it will be fired pretty late in the whole process. In Safari and Firefox the loading div is visible as long the other page isn't loaded yet, enough data for the browser to start rendering. When I would use the onload it wouldn't add any value, if it does already (client wish).

Comment: Could you not use one single page for your application? (surely one of the main advantages of AJAX)

You could use something like jQuery BBQ to allow back/forward functionality and provide different entry points.

Comment: Everything is possible, but I prefer the old fashion way with some extra flavor. Anyway I still have the feeling that there is a solution for IE. Just can't come up with it yet.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the # before the id on the jQuery selector:

```
$("#applicationdisabler").show();
```